# Android - Dynamically changing ImageView in a class

Tags: android, xml, class, android-manifest

So my problem is I am currently trying to dynamically change an ImageView when an item is selected from a listview. It gives me an `"cocktailName cannot be resolved or is not a field"` error
CocktailMenu class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.ListActivity;

public class CocktailMenu extends Activity {

    String classes[] = {"Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan", "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita", "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada", "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour", "White_Russian"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cocktail_menu);
        Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bByList);
        Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRandomCocktail);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ourIntent = new Intent(CocktailMenu.this, Menu.class);
                ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name", classes);
                startActivity(ourIntent);
                }
            }
        );
        b2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int random = (int) (Math.random() * classes.length);
                Intent i = new Intent(CocktailMenu.this, CocktailDetail.class);
                i.putExtra("cocktail_name", classes[random]);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
            );
    }
}
```

Menu class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Menu extends ListActivity {

    String classes[] = { "Bloody_Mary", "Capirinha", "Cosmopolitan",
            "Cuba_Libre", "Daiquiri", "Mai_Tai", "Manhattan", "Margarita",
            "Martini", "Mint_Julep", "Mojito", "Old_Fashoned", "Pina_Colada",
            "Screwdriver", "Singapore_Sling", "Tom_Collins", "Whiskey_Sour",
            "White_Russian" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        ;
        Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, CocktailDetail.class);
        ourIntent.putExtra("cocktail_name",classes);
        startActivity(ourIntent);

    };
}
```

CocktailDetail class

```
package com.drunktxtapp;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;


    public class CocktailDetail extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.cocktaildetail);
            Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonYoutube);
            String cocktailName = getIntent().getStringExtra("cocktail_name");
            TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textCocktailName);
            t1.setText(cocktailName);
            ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
            //imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cocktailName);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Alt-ehDc3fc")));
                    }
            });
        }
    }
```

CocktailMenu XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/beer"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bByList"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:padding="25dp"
        android:text="Cocktail List"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bRandomCocktail"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Random Cocktail"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you more clear what you want?

Comment: What I want to do Is dynamaclly change the ImageView in the cocktaildetail.xml when I pick an item from the listview in the MyMenu class. I have a bit of code in the CocktailDetail class but its throwing an error

Comment: You want to change image in imageview or total imageview with another.

Comment: Yes I have a few images loaded into the drawable folder all with the same name's as the items in the listview (so iv an bloody_mary image as well as it being in my listview) So if I select a cocktail from the listview is should change the default image in the cocktaildetail.xml

Comment: Where is your image view in list item. i didn't saw any image views in your list view item.

Comment: Can you see my problem its in this line of code : `ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageCocktail);
            imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cocktailName);`

Comment: There shouldn't be an ImageView in the list item because the ListView only displays the List. Then when selected it sends the name of the cocktail onto the CocktailDetail class and should chang the image in this line of code `imageView1.setImageResource(R.drawable.cocktailName);`

Comment: Stacktrace would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do an if statement

```
int resourceId;
if (cocktailName.equals(Bloody_Mary)
{
   resourceId = R.drawable.name_for_bloody_mary;
}
else if (cocktailName.equals(Capirinha)
{
   resourceId = R.drawable.name_for_Capirinha;
}
else if ......

imageView1.setImageResource(resourceId);
```